# Why can't I check if a string is a substring of each string in a list by using list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have the following code:

```
MFII_files = ['patrick', 'domccc', 'joseph', 'harry']

file_name = 'ccc'

if file_name in MFII_file for MFII_file in MFII_files: 
    print('yes')
```

But when I run it, it says invalid syntax pointing to the `for`. Why does this not work?

Comment: You didn't use a list comprehension.

Comment: That is not a list comprehension, and list comprehensions are for *creating lists*

Comment: That's a generator expression, and the generator it produces (if, in this case, it is surrounded by parentheses) is *always* truthy, whether or not it actually produces any values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) to perform this check instead.

```py
if any(file_name in MFII_file for MFII_file in MFII_files):
```

`any` takes an iterable and returns a result indicating whether any element of the iterable was true. In this case, we can conveniently pass a generator expression.

Comment: Ahh of course... silly me. How can I forget the `any()`. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use list comprehension, then I suggest something like:

```
selection = [file for file in MFII_files if file_name in file]

if selection: 
    print('yes')
```

Comment: This creates a spurious in-memory list and doesn't short-circuit

Comment: @user2390182 That goes beyond what was asked. Since the OP is interested in a list comprehension method, I think this answer is relevant.